# Are there recent TeX Distributions for the Mac that DON'T contain latexmk?

Tags: mac, latexmk

The title says it all. I know there are folks using all sorts of TeX Distributions on the Mac (TeX Live [installed by MacTeX or directly from TUG], MikTeX, MacPorts, Fink?, etc.) do recent versions all supply latexmk in the distribution?

Comment: Isn't both macports and fink again texlive? Any respectable larex installation provides what is on CTAN (if allowed of course), so latexmk and say arara is provided.

Comment: What is your use case exactly? Are you developing a LaTeX-related program for Mac that uses latexmk? Or are you writing a book/article/blog post about LaTeX on Mac and you want to make sure it's accurate? Or you are thinking of switching to another distribution yourself and you want to keep using latexmk? Or something else? Each use case warrants a somewhat different answer to this question I think - although I agree with @daleif that probably all of them have it or make it easy to install it if it is not in some default/minimal/base version of the distribution.

Comment: @Marijn : I put together and maintain the latexmk based engines for TeXShop. Since the start TeXShop has had an internal copy of latexmk because, at the time, it wasn't being distributed with TeX Live (installed via MacTeX). The situation has changed for quite a few years now and I am thinking about making the (simple) change to using latexmk from the installed TeX Distribution. Of course not all folks install TeX Live so I would like to know if I need an existance check or can just depend upon it being in place.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification. I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but don't you need an existence check always? The binaries may not be available if the user has removed, renamed, unsymlinked, somethingelsed them I guess?

Comment: @Marijn : you are correct. I wasn't thinking about the possibility of have no TeX Distribution at all or one that is incorrectly set up.

Comment: @daleif : Although MacPorts does have what it calls a texlive package, it doesn't give full installation, and is significantly modified compared with a standard TeX Live installation.  Notably tlmgr isn't present.  (I think latexmk is also missing; MacPorts has a separate latexmk package.)

Comment: @JohnCollins it's probably a similar repacking as the debian one.